# Mocha Does Not Fail When Tests Wrapped in describe()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have relatively simple mocha & chai test setup. Unfortunately when I run mocha the test that should definitely fail passes! Here is my test case.

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var nock = require('nock');
var request = require('request');

var testUrl = 'http://test.wicked.ti';
var getItems = function(url, callback) {               
     request.get(url + '/items',function(err, data) {
     if(err) throw err;
     callback(data);
  });
};

describe('Sample Unit Tests', function(){
  it('I am making sure the correct rest endpoint is called', function() {
    var request = nock(testUrl)
      .get('/items')
      .reply(200, {});

    getItems(testUrl, function(data) {
      console.log(data);            // This runs
      expect(true).to.equal(false);  // This should always fail!
      done();
    });  
  });
});
```

Wrapping the `expect(true).to.equal(false)` in try catch throws an error (shown below) that is caught just fine. That is

```
   it('I am making sure the correct rest endpoint is called', function() {
    var request = nock(testUrl)
      .get('/items')
      .reply(200, {});

    getItems(testUrl, function(data) {
      console.log(data);            // This runs

      // Adding try/catch block
      try { expect(true).to.equal(false); } catch(err) { console.error(err) } 

      done();
    });
```

And this is the logged error

```
{ [AssertionError: expected true to equal false]
  message: 'expected true to equal false',
  showDiff: true,
  actual: true,
  expected: false }
```

I have been racking my hair trying to figure out what I might be doing wrong without success! The question is what Am I missing? If it is any help I have tried to write this outside `describe()` & `it()` blocks and it runs just okay.

Comment: try `it('something', function(done){ ... `?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're running a synchronous test so it doesn't wait for the async function to complete. To make it asynchronous your callback needs an argument:

```
it('...', function(done) {
  //                 |
  //                 |
  //        this is where "done" comes from and it's
  //         the missing bug in your code
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a minor detail I was missing. I didn't realize I needed to pass done argument. Where is it documented?

Comment: @Willa: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code. It's easy to miss. Fun fact: most people don't know that all functions have a `.length` property that reflects how many arguments the function is defined to have. I used it in a library I wrote to figure out how many values to pass to the callback. Mocha uses the same mechanism to figure out if the test is sync or async.